# Where can I report an issue with ASP.NET Browsers File?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, bug

While working with an ASP.NET application on Chrome for Android I discovered that `Request.Browser.Cookies` returns False for that browser (despite the browser supporting cookies). [Based on what I've read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpbrowsercapabilitiesbase.cookies.aspx), this indicates a problem with the database which ASP.NET uses to look up information about different UserAgents. The fact that it returns False means that the database is either missing Chrome for Android, or has invalid data for it.

What is the a proper place to report IIS issues like this?

Comment: This might be a stretch, but surely there are Microsoft developer channels you could post this as a bug in?

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the wonderful world of bug reporting on a Microsoft product. I hope you don't struggle with substance abuse, and if you do please contact your sponsor before reading further.

[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/) is one way to communicate with the product teams for various Microsoft titles. However, IIS does not appear to be one that accepts bug reports.

The [IIS.net](http://www.iis.net/) forums are a place that you can apparently, if you're lucky and the tides are just right, have your bug report seen by a Microsoft employee. [Witness this example](http://forums.iis.net/p/1156993/1901250.aspx).

What you might be able to to is track down the contact information for one of the product evangelists for IIS (I found one so far, but won't post his info here) and send an email/tweet/smoke signal about your concern. The evangelists that I've dealt with are pretty nice people and will work to get your feedback to the proper people. That's not a guarantee though.

Another option us the [Microsoft Support main site](http://support.microsoft.com/) and snoop around for some means of contacting Microsoft concerning the product. From there you can drill down into the IIS family.

You might also want to go to the [Microsoft Connect feedback page](http://connect.microsoft.com/Connect) and request an IIS Connect program.

If by this time you've come to the conclusion that you're going to have a tough time directly reporting an IIS bug - you are correct. Remember, the first stage in healing is to recognize that there is a problem. Apparently Microsoft doesn't want to recognize problems with IIS... ?

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET uses a series of configuration files to determine (based on http request agent strings) browser capabilities.  This is a feature of ASP.NET (not IIS).  You can generally find these files here: %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\CONFIG\Browsers

As such, this post would probably be better served on StackOverflow.

Server side browser capability detection is one of the most difficult to maintain.  Literally, as soon as these browser capability config files are generated, they are out of date.  So, even if you downloaded them daily, you'd constantly be out of date.

In order to **truly** perform browser capability detection, your best bet will be to use client side browser feature detection (such as Modernizr).  This will be close to 100% accurate.  You just can't rely on a server side solution in this case.
-Chris